# Sql Queries for finding the sales trend

Tags: sql, datetime, intervals

Suppose ,I have a table which has all the billing records. Now I want to see the sales trend for a user given time duration group by each 3 days ...what should be the sql query regarding this?

please help,Otherwise I am gone ...

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. Are you looking for what product had the most sales during a given time period? Also could you post some of the table structures you are working with?

Comment: how would anyone help you without any example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I can only give a vague suggestion as per the question, however you may want to have a derived column with a standardised date (as per MS date format, just a number per day) that you could then use a modulus (3) on so that days are equal per 3 day period.  You can then group and aggregate over this column to get the values for a 3 day period.  Obviously to display the date nicely you would have to multiply back and convert your column as well.

Again I'm not sure of the specifics, but I think this general idea could be achieved to get a result (may well not be the best way so it would help to add more to the question...)